# SQL Instances and Wait Locks

Tags: sql-server, wait, multiple-instances

I have a SQL Server with one instance and lots of databases.

One of the databases (SUSDB) causes locks which increase the number of wait tasks. This in turn affects the performance of the other databases whilst the process (WSUS Cleanup) runs.

If the SUSDB was installed in a separate instance, would the wait tasks be confined to that instance and therefore not affect the main instance?

I think the problem is just badly designed queries/indexes in the SUSDB. The server has plenty of resource, the CPU generally ticks over at about 2-5% and it has about 380GB RAM.

I appreciate that memory should be allocated to the instances, so taking 12GB from the 380GB available shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: if you dont care about resource wasting, yes the problem would be solved by moving the issued db to another instance. However i'm not a fan of resource wasting so i would recommend you to analyze your locking queries and tune/troubleshout them.

Comment: When you say "One of the databases causes locks" what do you mean?  Is it one process blocking another?

Comment: I agree with MJH, we need more information. If there is truly "blocking" that you encounters (like one session has a exclusive lock because of a modification and another is blocked trying to acquire a shared lock because of a read), then separating to a different instance won't change things. The blocking occurs "within" that database and doesn't affect other databases. So, dig deeper in wait stats and see what type of wait stats you are seeing. I generally use Glenn's query for wait stats in: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/category/dmv-queries/

Comment: My guess is that the queries that are causing the issue would stop working when you move the database to a separate instance. But it would likely fix your performance issue. Adding a linked server could get the queries working again, but probably at the cost of performance....

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

The queries are inbuilt queries of Microsoft WSUS, which uses Stored procedures.  This happens when I run the Cleanup process, in particular the Delete Obsolete updates process.

When the stored procedure runs, monitoring SQL Profiler shows Wait Task count increase.  The process is working, but just taking time to cycle through the updates for deletion (currently 3500).  When this happens we notice an impact on traffic accessing other databases for production systems.